# How do I make Gtk Headerbars look okay in Elementary?

Tags: gtk

I know that Elementary has its own Headerbar style, but if you use any Gnome apps (as we all of course will), their headerbars often look flatly bad in Elementary, despite having nearly identical design language. Here for example is what Gnome Disk Utility looks like -- an essential app for most Linux users.

[image: screenshot of ugly rendered headerbar]

Is there anything that can be done to make those apps look at least a little bit presentable?

Answer (score -1):

Well I had similar problem running `playonlinux`. In that case you have a double head bar.
If you type in terminal:

```
GTK_CSD=0 name-of-application-to-launch-it
```

Example:

```
GTK_CSD=0 playonlinux
```

it is a workaround to have the good head bar design.
Not still a "fix" anyway.

I don't know if this could work in your case as well.

Comment: Hi Gianwt, welcome to eOS SE. Your participation is much appreciated. Here's a little **tip:** When you add *keywords* or *commands* in your question, answer & comment, mark them as *code*.

Comment: It's not exactly an issue of a double headerbar; this for example won't fix the problem of Glade, Disk Tool, or other Gnome apps looking wonky. All that does is toggle client-side decorations, which in general, you do want for apps with a headerbar.